# Garbage collection tuning/performance degradation for neo4j bulk .csv import

Tags: neo4j, garbage-collection, csv-import

I am running a bulk import of data into a neo4j instance (I have run against 2.2.0 community and enterprise editions as well as 2.1.7 community) running in server mode.  My application creates a bunch of nodes in memory, and will peridoically stop to write a series .csv files and send cypher to the neo4j instance to upload the files.  (this was done due to performance issues with running the application using the plain old REST API).

Overall, I'm looking to upload something like 150-5000 million nodes, so this is, in principle, the type of thing that neo4j claims to be able to handle relatively well.

Well, anyway, what I'm noticing when I run this against production data is that the application runs in two states -- one where the csv upload processes between 2k-8k of nodes per second, and one where it processes between 80-200 nodes per second.  The two states are interwoven when you look at the upload as a time series, and as time goes on, it spends increasingly long amounts of time in the slow state.

Nodes are created through a series of

```
MERGE (:{NODE_TYPE} {csvLine.key = n.primaryKey}) on create set [PROPERTY LIST];
```

statements, and I have indexes on everything that I'm doing merges against.  This doesn't feel like a degradation in the insert statements, because the slowdown is not linear, but rather bimodal, this feels like there are garbage collection in the neo4j instance.  What is the best way to tune the neo4j JVM garbage collector for frequent bulk inserts?

neo4j.properties:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=50M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=500M
#neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.mapped_memory=10M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=100M
#neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=130M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M
```

neo4j-wrapper.conf:

```
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:hashCode=5

wrapper.java.initmemory=8194
wrapper.java.maxmemory=8194
```

This felt like the sweet spot for both the overall heap memory and the neostore stuff.  Increasing the overall heap degraded performance.  That said, the neo4j garbage collection logs frequently have that GC (Allocation Failure) message.

EDIT: in response to Michael Hunger:

the machine has 64 GB of RAM, and nothing seems to be maxed out.  It also seems like only a small number of cores are being used at any time.  Garbage collector profiling shows that the garbage collector seems to be running quite frequently.

The exact cypher statements are, for example:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 110000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///home/jschirmer/Event_2015_4_773476.csv' AS csvLine MERGE (s:Event {primaryKey: csvLine.primaryKey}) ON CREATE SET s.checkSum= csvLine.checkSum,s.epochTime= toInt(csvLine.epochTime),s.epochTimeCreated= toInt(csvLine.epochTimeCreated),s.epochTimeUpdated= toInt(csvLine.epochTimeUpdated),s.eventDescription= csvLine.eventDescription,s.fileName= csvLine.fileName,s.ip= csvLine.ip,s.lineNumber= toInt(csvLine.lineNumber),s.port= csvLine.port,s.processPid= csvLine.processPid,s.rawEventLine= csvLine.rawEventLine,s.serverId= csvLine.serverId,s.status= toInt(csvLine.status);

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 110000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///home/jschirmer/Event__File_2015_4_773476.csv' AS csvLine MATCH (n:SC_CSR{primaryKey: csvLine.Event_id}), (s:File{fileName: csvLine.File_id}) MERGE n-[:DATA_SOURCE]->s;
```

Though there are serveral such statements being made
I have tried a single concurrent transaction as well as running several (~3) such statements in parallel (which gives a roughly 2x improvement).  I've tried tuning the periodic commit frequency, and the size of the file.  It seems that this maximizes performance when the csv file is roughly 100k lines, which means that really, the periodic commit can be off.

I have not run profile on the staments.  I will do that, but I thought that the eager merget problem was avoided by using MERGE ... on create statements.

Answer (score 0):

IN general your config looks ok, what RAM does your machine have?

For the things you merge against I'd recommend  constraint instead of an index.

What's your tx size? And how many concurrent tx do you run?

Instead of your generic merge statement (which wouldn't compile) can you share the concrete statements?

Did you profile the statements? Perhaps you run into the eager pipe problem:

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/

Do you use periodic commit?

How large are you CSV files?

See: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/